# Which is the best development/production environment for Django projects?

Tags: django, architecture, development-environment

**A bit of background**

I work for a little company as Django developer. The previous developer left the company and I am the only developer (that is the reason they were looking for a Django developer). The company has a simple web application that needs to be mantained and scaled. It seems that the company is getting sales and incomes are increasing. There is a possibility to hire another developer in the short or mid-term. Right now I am analizing possible improvements. This is my first professional job as Django developer, but I achieved to deploy some little personal projects in the past. As you can imagine I am not an expert at all.

**The issue**

We use a Ubuntu VPS for development, using Django's integrated web server. And another Ubuntu VPS for production, using Nginx+Gunicorn. We use git for version control. The only user we use (for everything) in both VPS is root. I don't work locally in my computer, but connected via ssh to the servers. These are my insights about the structure:

1. Use of root is unsafe. No doubt about it and we should change this.
2. What if another developer is hired? Could we work together in the development server?

**The question**

As the title says, I want to know which would be the perfect working structure for a developers team. After googling a few hours my approach would be something like this:

1. Production server.
2. Testing server (replicating as much as possible the production server).
3. Development environment. Every developer should work and test their code locally in their computers before testing it in the Testing server.
4. Use of Git for version control.
5. Use of non-root users for both testing and production servers.

This is just my point of view and I haven't even tried it. I would appreciate you to share your knowledge and experiences.

Thanks in advance!